# Add-in doesn't listed in Outlook add-list section

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

After running the setup.exe file, I'm getting the following success message:

> The Microsoft Office customization was successfully installed

But, after opening the Outlook, the add-in does not listed in  the Options>Add-in section. It is also doesn't listed in disabled section. It's simply not there.

I have to mention. This is the first time I've encountered this type of a problem. I've already had a dozen of successful installation, but not this time.

Any suggestion what may be a problem?

Comment: Which version of Outlook are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Other websites have suggested to uninstall your Add-in and run setup.exe again and use the option "Run as Administrator."

Also, Microsoft has an Inbox Repair Tool that fixes a lot of issues.